# Which library gives this cool edit-in-place effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Which library gives this cool edit-in-place effect?

A text tag on a web page: mouse over it and the "edit-pencil" appears next to it. You click the edit-pencil and the tag+pencil turns into a super-simple edit of that field, with accept & cancel. I love the simplicity. I could grind it out from scratch. But surely this is from a library or recipe?

[image]

[image]

The function that gets called behind the scenes is `xhrDynamicLabelUpdate()` but my searches turn nothing up.

I found [X-Editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) which is close, but not quite as simple imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Syncfusion Essential Studio In Place Editor](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/inplace-editor/default) is an option to consider.

[image: Syncfusion EJ2 In Place Editor]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.